# Entered wrong passport issue date on visa application

Tags: airports, philippines, pakistan

I just recently applied for a visa and I mistakenly put the wrong year on the issue date but my visa was granted. I sent the embassy an email about it but I didn't receive any response. Now I'm worried that I might get denied boarding for this. Will it cause a problem?

The travel is soon and I am still worrying.

Comment: Only the consular office could fix it. (Nowadays it is all digital, so probably all systems have the wrong date). Did you receive a letter with the visa? Read carefully, possibly there is the way to contact them if there are errors (and check original applications: are you sure you didn't wrote the wrong year).

Comment: Is only the issue date which is wrong or also the validity dates?

Comment: Are you saying that you mentioned a previous visa in your application but put the wrong year in the description of the visa? Or does the visa actually have the wrong issue date printed on it?

Comment: You "put the wrong year on the issue date" - the issue date *of what*? The only place you give an issue date when applying for a visa is when asked about *your passport's issue date*. If that's what you did wrong, but you were issued a visa anyway, then it didn't matter to whichever authority issued the visa - they may have noticed that you made an error and simply ignored it. What matters is that you have a valid visa in a (presumably) valid passport. You're not going to be denied boarding (a least not for this reason).

Comment: Thank you so much for the answers. I had a mistake on typing the issued year date of my passport on the visa I got 2022 and I wrote 2023 I got confuse since I'm making visa for me and my daughter she has 2023. I'm just worried because immigration in my country is known for being strict.

Comment: Note that we cannot guarantee anything.  "Some random people on the Internet said it will be okay" won't have much affect on an immigration officer.

Answer (score 5):

You won't get denied because of that. When you applied and as your visa is granted, they probably rectified on their end. If they couldn't rectify on their end, they would have denied your visa. While boarding, what matters most is your valid passport and visa copy.

Comment: Same goes with evisa?